# Talend routine add maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, talend

In Talend Data Integration Studio (7.0.1), I have a custom routine, where I want to use a Maven dependency (JavaFaker).

By the project explorer window, I can add maven depnedency on CustomRoutine project.

After refreshing, maven dependency javaFaker (and it sub dependencies) looks loaded, are displayed in project explorer, and autocompletion is ok on routine code.

But when I try to run the job, no way to make it work: Class is not found (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError).

Sometimes maven dependencies config from project routines is reseted (when I go in talend main maven project setting I think).

What are steps to use a maven Library in a Talend routine? Add an external jar is complicated because of sub dependencies in maven librries…